# Wrong Screen Resolution

Tags: display, display-resolution

I just finished installing Ubuntu on a new partition, and everything seems to be working apart from the faulty display resolution.

**Graphics card / driver used (on Windows partition):** *AMD Radeon R9 370*

**Resolution expected:** *2560 x 1440*

Could anyone help me out with this?

Cheers.

Comment: Edit your post to include, graphix driver used, resolution you got and the one expected. I guess you might to install proprietary graphic driver

Comment: @solsTiCe Post updated. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't you get this option in system display settings? I haven't seen more than 1090×1080p yet is your machine with 2k/4k screen?

Comment: @sardapv Shows "Unknown Display" in display settings. I'm using the following monitor: https://www.amazon.com/PG279Q-2560x1440-G-SYNC-Gaming-Monitor/dp/B017EVR2VM

Comment: Did my solution solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the official Ubuntu how-to guide:https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD.

open your terminal and type:

```
 sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

Then generate a fresh xorg.conf, before you reboot:

```
 sudo amdconfig --initial
 sudo apt-get update
```

Reboot.

Comment: *NOTE: As of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, the AMD Catalyst or fglrx driver is no longer supported by Canonical nor AMD. If you have an AMD GPU and wish to run any Ubuntu version 16.04 LTS or newer, Canonical recommends using the open source alternatives: radeon and amdgpu. Which one you should use depends on which GPU you have - newer AMD GPUs should use amdgpu while older AMD GPUs should use radeon.*